# Double Pointer in Metal

Tags: arrays, swift, metal, metalkit, metal-performance-shaders

I'm trying to run a Metal compute shader on an array of arrays. I thought that because we use pointers to provide arrays to the shader, the logical solution would be to use a double pointer when working on a 2D array.

My kernel function is in the form:

```
kernel void foo(device float** array2D [[buffer(0)]], uint2 pid [[thread_position_in_grid]]) {
    ...
}
```

When I use `device float** array2D [[buffer(0)]]` as a parameter in the Metal shader function, I get an error:

> Invalid address space qualification for buffer pointee type 'device float *'

I'm assuming this is because the compiler is interpreting `device float *` as the address space qualification (which is not valid).
My question is: **How do I tell the compiler that I'm using a double pointer?** and if I can't use double pointers for some reason, **What's a good workaround for working on a 2D array?**

*Sidenote:* I know that it's possible to combine the elements in all the arrays into one array, do the computation on the single array and then divide the array back up into its smaller arrays. However, this is really inefficient and takes a long time. (I'm working with big arrays hence the use of Metal).

Comment: Are the inner arrays the same length?  If so it's more inefficient to break them into smaller arrays.  It's harder to work with in Metal, but also on the CPU it's hell on L2 caching.  Also how dynamic is the array of arrays once you create it?  Are you adding and removing arrays?  Or is it like a matrix/image where you just create the size you need and once created it stays the same size?

Comment: The collection of arrays represents different plots at particular times. The 1st array is the plot at t=0 seconds, the 2nd array is the plot at t=1 seconds, 3rd array is the plot at t= 2 seconds and so on. The plots are the same length but working with all of them as one continuous array doesn't make sense for my project and combining them up into 1 array and then splitting them back up would be so inefficient that it would miss the whole point of using Metal in the first place.

Comment: Hmm.. I've never had to do that with Metal, but this link about argument buffers seems to have facilities that might do the trick: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/buffers/using_argument_buffers_with_resource_heaps In particular the section on resource heaps seems relevant.

Comment: It also might work to set up multiple command queues, one per plot (up to a limit).  Then use them to create `MTLCommandBuffers` and commit in parallel using `DispatchQueue.async`.  I'm not sure if it will work, but it's worth a try.

Comment: Thank you! I'll take a look!

Comment: I come here with the same question. But I have a comment on your side note. Dealing with the long 1d array is more efficient for the computer, but more difficult for our brains.

Answer (score 0):

### Updated answer

In comments (and revised question) you clarify that you can't combine them into a flat array.  I don't have an answer that I know will work, but rather something to try.

Create an array of `MTLCommandQueues`.  The idea is to create and commit separate `MTLCommandBuffer`s on different `MTLCommandQueue`s in parallel using `DispatchQueue.async`.

I'm sure there's some limit on the number of command queues you can create so you can probably use the completion handler for each command buffer to chain to creating another one for an inner array waiting to be processed.

### Original answer

I think you need to put your arrays in one flat array.

Assuming the inner arrays are the same length, and that `pid` is the "row" and "column" of the value you want to do your computation for, you would pass in the array length as one of your parameters to the shader:

```cpp
kernel void foo(device float* array2D [[buffer(0)]], device uint rowLen [[buffer(1)]], uint2 pid [[thread_position_in_grid]]) {
    doSomeComputation(array2D[rowLen * pid.y + pid.x]); 
}
```

If the arrays are different lengths, you'll need to pass in an array of offsets into the `array2D` for the starts of all the rows.

```cpp
kernel void foo(device float* array2D [[buffer(0)]], device uint* rowOffsets [[buffer(1)]], uint2 pid [[thread_position_in_grid]]) {
    doSomeComputation(array2D[rowOffsets[pid.y] + pid.x]); 
}
```